# TomEE plus 1.7.1 in Linux hangs during server startup on myfaces-impl-2.1.15.jar

Tags: linux, jsf, myfaces, apache-tomee

Tomee plus 1.7.1 server was hanging on server startup and we debugged it found that myfaces-impl-2.1.15.jar is causing the problem. If we remove this jar from the server lib, server starts fine.

Same distribution works fine on windows environment but we see this problem on linux server. Appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloaded myfaces-api-2.2.7.jar and myfaces-impl-2.2.7.jar from https://myfaces.apache.org/ and replaced older version of myfaces jars.

I don't see the server hanging after replacing jars with latest jar files.